# Storing SOAP response as hash

Tags: perl, soap, hash

I'm trying to store the response from a Perl (v5.12.4) SOAP call (SQL query) as a hash for further processing while maintaining the structure of the data.  The columns will vary so I'd like to be able to build the column keys dynamically.  Here is an example of the reply:

```
$VAR1 = {
      'row' => [
               #0
               {
                 'column1' => '',
                 'column2' => 'f',
                 'column3' => '0',
                 'column4' => '',
                 'column5' => 'f',
                 'column6' => '0',
                 'column7' => 'f',
               },
            ]
       };
```

I'm interested in the column names and values.  I've made some (comical) attempts at handling this, such as:

```
unless ($res->fault) {
  $Data::Dumper::Indent = 3;
  my (%reply) = $res->paramsall();
  foreach my $keys (keys %reply) {
    print "$keys\n";
  }
}
```

This gets a "Reference found where even-sized list expected at script.pl line...".  Any point in the right direction here is much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This :

```
$res->paramsall()
```

almost certainy returns a hashref.

So what you are doing is assigning the hashref to the 1st key of %reply.

```
my %reply = %{ $res->paramsall() };
```

Will probably work.

You should take a look at [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) for some methods to work with refrerence structures.

Dereferencing hashes with my %hash = %{ } makes a copy of the referenced hash.
You can work directly with hashrefs like this :

```
my $reply = $res->paramsall(); 

foreach my $key1 (keys %$reply) { 
  foreach my $key2 (keys %{ $reply->{$key1} }) { 
    print " $key2: " . $reply->{$key1}{$key2} . "\n"; 
  } 
}
```

In the 1st code example in your reply, this :

```
$reply{$key2}->{$key2}
```

should read :

```
$reply{$key1}{$key2}
```

since everything is already dereferenced.

Comment: Hi John,

That worked great, thanks!  I'm having some issues when trying to access the key/value's in the hash.  I'm using:

    foreach my $key1 (keys %reply) {
 foreach my $key2 (keys %{$reply{$key1}}) {
            print "  $key2: " . $reply{$key2}->{$key2} . "\n";
 }
    }

But I'm getting "Not a HASH reference at script.pl line...."

Any advice on parsing the hash?

Thanks!

Comment: Well, I found a way to get to the info but I don't think it's the most elegant solution....but it works:

my $count = 0;
 until ($reply{'row'}[$count] eq undef) {
            my %newHash = %{$reply{'row'}[$count]};
            while (my ($key,$value) = each %newHash) {
  print "$key = $value\n";
            }
            $count++;
If anyone has a suggestion to refine my solution, I'm all ears.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks again John.  I'll definitely read through perlreftut and also read through perldoc perldsc, but didn't find and example for this (unless I missed it).  When using the code you provided above, I'm still getting the "Not a HASH reference..." reply.  I could be missing something and will keep checking and reading your suggested material.